# Instagram getting empty response from /oauth/access_token

Tags: php, instagram-api

I have a small PHP page that is logging into Instagram and downloading the users photos. The first time I use it and log on, no problem. Often if I come back later and try it, it doesn't ask me to log on (I'm already logged on) but, the response from /oauth/access_token is empty. If I use the browser back button and try again, everything works.

Here's the code that I'm using. The apiData contains the client_id, etc.

```
<?php

define('CLIENT_ID', 'xxxx');
define('CLIENT_SECRET', 'xxx');
define('REDIRECT_URL', 'xxxx');
define('AUTH_TOKEN_URL', 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token');
define('API_OAUTH_URL', 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize');


function fetchData($url, $apiData){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($apiData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiData));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return json_decode($result);
  }
```